# Bootstrap minimum width grid

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Using twitter bootstrap using a fluid row setup I have

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span4">...</div>
    <div class="span8">...</div>
</div>
```

What I want is to give the first div (with class span4) a minimum width of 275px without upsetting the layout of the second. I've tried just adding `min-width: 275px` but that makes the second div move to the next line. Is there a way to do this properly?

Answer (score 12):

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span4" style="min-width: 275px">...</div>
    <div class="span8">...</div>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Worked for me. It moves the second div to the new line only if the second div has less then ~66% of screen space.

http://jsfiddle.net/daniilr/DAw6p/embedded/result/ ([get the code](http://jsfiddle.net/daniilr/DAw6p/))

Comment: Yes this is the case which is causing the problem when I move the screen to a smaller size (but there is still enough space for the second div to fit)

Comment: div in this (http://jsfiddle.net/daniilr/DAw6p/embedded/result/) example moves to the new line only when it has less then 66% of screen. Do you expect another behaviour?

Comment: @Daniil : I was looking for the same here. Actually, I want 275px on the left one and the right one to never move down at all. Is there some obvious way to do this?

Comment: @Ronnie Kilsbo overflow: auto + don't use percentage width anywhere probably will help

Comment: @Daniil I have both `overflow: auto` on both columns and the only width I set (other than by using the spanX attributes) is on the left column with `min-width: 250px`. Still, the second (right) column pops down below the first (left) column when the window is rezised down horizontally.

If I remove the `min-width: 250px` on the left column the right column stays where it's supposed to be and is resized with the window.

Is there a way to force the right column to stay, no matter what?

Answer (score 1):

I have similar issue, too. And I try solve this problem with css and bootstrap. But I can't find a solution. So I solved this problem with jQuery.

### My Situation

```
<div id="text" class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-2" style="min-width: 320px"></div>
<div id="image" class="col-sm-7" ></div>
```

When window width is narrow, then `#image` will move to next line. Because `#text` width can not be loosed anymore from 320px. So `#image` can not occupy its width, and have to move next line.

### How I Solved It

Calculate `#image` width each window size. And CSS is not proper for this work. So I should use jQuery.

```
$(window).ready(function() {
    resizeImageWidth();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
        resizeImageWidth();
    });
});

var resizeImageWidth = function() {
    var text_minwidth = parseInt($('#text').css('width'));
    var text_marginLeft = parseInt($('#text').css('margin-left'));
    var image_marginLeft = parseInt($('#image').css('margin-left'));

    if ($(window).width() > 768) {
        var image_width = $(window).width() - (text_marginLeft + text_minwidth + image_marginLeft + 32);
        $('#image').width(image_width);
        console.log(image_width);
    } else {
        $('#image').width('');
    }
}
```

`resizeImageWidth` function will get `#text` width, margin-left, `#image` margin-left and more thing. Of course it can not fit your code. I should subtract these things. Please check what I have subtracted.

After render `div` can still move to next line. Maybe some elements is missing. So I subtract `30px` hardly. But this calculating still have error. So `div` can move next line in some `window` width. So I should subtract a further **2px** to prevent it. Ideally I should make more exact calculations.

In small display, this calculating did not be needed. So `if ($(window).width() > 768)` is needed. And this function should load in `$(window).ready`. If you load in `$(document).ready`, then CSS property is not incomplete. So calculating error is bigger.

Comment: Way too long and complicated, when CSS alone is enough.

Answer (score -1):

Bootstrap columns are flex items. You have to decide on one column which should shrink when the others have reached their min-width. This prevents elements moving to the next line.

here is a pretty codepen i made: https://codepen.io/timar/pen/VQWmQq/

In this case, we take the other span, reduce it to span1. Give it flex-grow and we have to overwrite bootstraps max-width property.

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span4 style="min-width: 275px;">...</div>
    <div class="span1 style=" flex-grow: 1; max-width:100%; "">...</div>
</div>
```

to be on the safe side you can reduce the second span only as much as necessary. i.e span6 . Adjust the max-width to the amount the normal span had, we had span8 100/12*8 = 66.66%

Comment: There is no "row-fluid" in Bootstrap 5, where it is easy to limit how large a column can become using this custom class: `.limited-width {max-width:30rem !important;}`.

Comment: This is for the very old Bootstrap. I thin now it's just `row`
Check here for a newer answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48755273/8385841