# min-width for column in Bootstrap grid system

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, grid-layout

I have following HTML with Bootstrap CSS.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4" style="min-width: 66px;">Name</div>
  <div class="col-sm-1" style="min-width: 120px;">Instance name</div>
  <div class="col-sm-7" style="min-width: 87px;">Due date</div>
</div>
```

Without 'min-width' a width of the second column in some cases is less than 120px and 'Instance name' isn't fully visible. So that I've added 'min-width' and width of row becomes more than 100% in that cases. The last column is wrapped into new line.

I want to have bootstrap dynamic column width and that Instance name doesn't disappeared when I reduce browser window size. How can I achieve such behavior?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Not sure if there is such a way to accomplish what you want.

The `col-sm-x` defines specific width percentages of your viewport, and if you provide custom values, then the accumulated width of all columns will either be more or less than 100%, which is not the desired behaviour.

Instead, you can provide multiple classes for the same div. Example:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-1">Name</div>
  <div class="col-sm-1 col-xs-3">Instance name</div>
  <div class="col-sm-7 col-xs-2">Due date</div>
</div>
```

If this is solution does not suffice, then you will most likely come up with a javascript solution of some sort that manually sets the width of the other divs.

There seems to be another, similar question previously posted here on stackoverflow. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11836131/bootstrap-minimum-width-grid).

[**Bootstrap Grid on W3Schools**](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_examples.asp)

Answer (score 26):

Bootstrap columns are flex items.
You have to decide on one column which should shrink when the others have reached their min-width.

For your example i chose the last one, "Due date" which normaly should be column-sm-7.
I give it the non-fixed column size "col", which will fill (flex-grow) the available space. In this example it would by default have 7 columns of space. `12 columns - 4 columns - 1 column = 7 columns`

More importantly  though it will start shrinking when the other columns reached their min-width.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4" style="min-width: 66px;">Name</div>
  <div class="col-sm-1" style="min-width: 120px;">Instance name</div>
  <div class="col" style="min-width: 87px;">Due date</div>
</div>
```

here is a codepen i made: https://codepen.io/timar/pen/VQWmQq/

what is also possible is to manually override the bootstrap column flex-properties like: gving the column `'col-sm-1'`  and `style="flex-grow: 1; max-width:100%;"`

Comment: This should be the answer.

Comment: Thank you ! class="col" is the answer.

Comment: This question wasn't previously answered as indicated at the top.  This is the best answer.

Answer (score 7):

Did you try changing your values for smaller resolutions?
For example

```
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4">Name</div>
  <div class="col-lg-1 col-sm-2">Instance name</div>
  <div class="col-lg-7 col-sm-6">Due date</div>
```

Bootstrap has options for different screen sizes, so you might want to check them out: http://getbootstrap.com/css/